# Wrong permissions on "make install"

Tags: installation, permissions, umask

When I compile and install tarballs using the usual `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`, the files and directories created always have wrong permissions. In particular, nothing that should have the group and user execute bits actually has them. I've been making do by tee-ing a copy of the make log and chmod-ing things as appropriate, but that's gotten increasingly annoying.

For example, I just tried to install the latest version of OCaml by its tarball using `./configure`, `make world`, and `sudo make install`. The result is that every `/usr/local/bin/ocaml*` has permissions `0744` rather than `0755` as you'd expect. Subdirectories in `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/` also have `0744` bits, preventing anyone who's not root from using those libraries.

`umask 022` before `make install` in a root shell is fruitless, as well. Furthermore, I have never had this problem with non-Ubuntu distributions, for what that's worth.

Like I said, this happens with *all* tarballs I use, so an answer like "`sudo apt-get install ocaml`" is missing the point.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the umask of your user (when compiling)?

Comment: Do the files in the compilation tree (e.g. `ocaml`) have 744 permissions as well? In addition to your umask, do you have strange mount options (post the output of `mount`)?

Comment: default umask of the user you are compiling can be found by  issuing 'umask' from terminal.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)